# Connecting a linux client into active directory

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, otrs

I have a linux server (opensuse 12.1) running OTRS 3.0.10.
And a primary domain controller running Windows Server 2008R2.
I've followed the howto page [here](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?wpid=98&front_id=18) and [here](http://doc.otrs.org/1.3/en/html/ldap-integration.html).
Obviously the `Net::LDAP` perl module is installed. 
However I cannot actually connect to AD.

Here's an excerpt from my configuration file in OTRS:
`/srv/otrs/Kernel/Config.pm`

```
#Enable LDAP authentication for Customers / Users
  $Self->{'Customer::AuthModule'} = 'Kernel::System::CustomerAuth::LDAP';
  $Self->{'Customer::AuthModule::LDAP::Host'} = '10.0.1.26';
  $Self->{'Customer::AuthModule::LDAP::BaseDN'} = 'ou=D1OU,ou=D1Users,dc=domain,dc=org,dc=za';
  $Self->{'Customer::AuthModule::LDAP::UID'} = 'sAMAccountName';

#The following is valid but would only be necessary if the
#anonymous user do NOT have permission to read from the LDAP tree
  $Self->{'Customer::AuthModule::LDAP::SearchUserDN'} = 'otrs';
  $Self->{'Customer::AuthModule::LDAP::SearchUserPw'} = 'Password';

#CustomerUser
#(customer user database backend and settings)
    $Self->{CustomerUser} = {
      Module => 'Kernel::System::CustomerUser::LDAP',
      Params => {
      Host => '10.0.1.26',
      BaseDN => 'OU=D1OU,OU=D1Users,DC=domain,DC=org,DC=za',
      SSCOPE => 'sub',
      UserDN =>'otrs',
      UserPw => 'Password',
    },

# customer unique id
    CustomerKey => 'sAMAccountName',
    # customer #
    CustomerID => 'mail',
    CustomerUserListFields => ['sAMAccountName', 'cn', 'mail'],
    CustomerUserSearchFields => ['sAMAccountName', 'cn', 'mail'],
    CustomerUserSearchPrefix => '',
    CustomerUserSearchSuffix => '*',
    CustomerUserSearchListLimit => 250,
    CustomerUserPostMasterSearchFields => ['mail'],
    CustomerUserNameFields => ['givenname', 'sn'],
    Map => [

      # note: Login, Email and CustomerID needed!
      # var, frontend, storage, shown, required, storage-type
      #[ 'UserSalutation', 'Title', 'title', 1, 0, 'var' ],
      [ 'UserFirstname', 'Firstname', 'givenname', 1, 1, 'var' ],
      [ 'UserLastname', 'Lastname', 'sn', 1, 1, 'var' ],
      [ 'UserLogin', 'Login', 'sAMAccountName', 1, 1, 'var' ],
      [ 'UserEmail', 'Email', 'mail', 1, 1, 'var' ],
      [ 'UserCustomerID', 'CustomerID', 'mail', 0, 1, 'var' ],
      [ 'UserPhone', 'Phone', 'telephonenumber', 1, 0, 'var' ],
      #[ 'UserAddress', 'Address', 'postaladdress', 1, 0, 'var' ],
      #[ 'UserComment', 'Comment', 'description', 1, 0, 'var' ],
    ],
  };
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

> ERROR: OTRS-CGI-10 Perl: 5.14.2 OS: linux Time: Mon Apr 30 10:50:52
>   2012
>
> Message: 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310020A, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT),
>   data 0, best match of:
>           'DC=domain,DC=org,DC=za' ^@
>
> Traceback (13338):     Module:
>   Kernel::System::CustomerUser::LDAP::CustomerUserDataGet (v1.62) Line:
>   614    Module: Kernel::System::CustomerUser::CustomerUserDataGet
>   (v1.61.2.1) Line: 283    Module: Kernel::System::CustomerAuth::Auth
>   (v1.34.2.2) Line: 166    Module:
>   Kernel::System::Web::InterfaceCustomer::Run (v1.56.2.5) Line: 203
>   Module:
>   ModPerl::ROOT::ModPerl::Registry::srv_otrs_bin_cgi_2dbin_customer_2epl::handler
>   (unknown version) Line: 46    Module: (eval) (v1.43.2.1) Line: 204
>   Module: ModPerl::RegistryCooker::run (v1.43.2.1) Line: 204    Module:
>   ModPerl::RegistryCooker::default_handler (v1.43.2.1) Line: 170
>   Module: ModPerl::Registry::handler (v1.99) Line: 31

I have a primary domain controller at `10.0.1.26` which is called: `servername.domain.org.za`. 
The pre-windows2000 domain name is `MYSERVER` which is also the pre-Windows2000 server name.
I created a user `otrs` which resides in the OU (organizational unit) `D1OU/D1Users` and is a member of the group `Domain users` and which has a non-expiring password (not 'password' of course, but something stronger).

**What I tried**
I've tried to get `Winbind` to talk to active directory, but it refuses unless I use the pre-Windows2000 credentials (`MYSERVER` **works**, `domain.org.za` **does not work**).
Other than that Winbind gets the data out of Active Directory with no problems.

**How do I fix this?**
I don't have a problem with supplying pre-windows2000 domain specs in the `Config.pm` file, but I don't know the format.
I would love to put proper LDAP params in, but perhaps I'm missing something.
So the question is, what do I need to change in `Config.pm` to get OTRS to authenticate against my AD?

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck using [Centrify](http://www.centrify.com/) or [PowerBroker Open](http://www.powerbrokeropen.org/) to handle the windows authentication. It should work if OTRS uses PAM.